# How to remove some Apache settings from Amazon Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: django, apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a strange issue with Elastic Beanstalk. I deployed a Django project to an auto-scalling EC2 instances.

In the `.ebextensions` directory I had a `python.config` file with these lines at the end:

```
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "myapp.settings_eb_staging"
    "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/django-myapp:$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: myapp/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "myapp/static/"
    "/favicon.ico": "myapp/static/site/img/favicon.ico"
```

When I deployed the project with

```
$ eb deploy
```

the deployment process created this Apache configuration which can be found at `/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`:

```
Alias /favicon.ico /opt/python/current/app/myapp/static/site/img/favicon.ico
<Directory /opt/python/current/app/myapp/static/site/img/favicon.ico>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

This was obviously wrong, because the `favicon.ico` is a file, not a directory.

So I tried to remove the last line from `python.config` file:

<strike>`"/favicon.ico": "myapp/static/site/img/favicon.ico"`</strike>

and then redeployed the project.

The problem is that the Apache directive stays there. I also tried to remove the directive manually, but after the next deploy it appears again. I even tried to rebuild environment, but it still created the wrong Apache configuration directive.

How can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, `wsgi.conf` configuration file can be overwritten in `.ebextensions/python.config` file. This is what I did:

1. SSH to the EC2 instance by `eb ssh` and get the content of `wsgi.conf` with `cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi.conf`.
2. Create a file `.ebextensions/wsgi.conf` and copy the content of the previous step there. Remove the Apache directives about static directory and favicon.
3. Modify the `.ebextensions/python.config` and add a command to copy `wsgi.conf` to `/tmp/` directory (which is probably used during the deployment process):

   ```
   container_commands:
     01_refresh_apache_conf:
       command: "cp .ebextensions/wsgi.conf /tmp/wsgi.conf"
     02_migrate:
       command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
   leader_only: true
     03_collectstatic:
       command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

   option_settings:
     "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
       DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "myapp.settings_eb_staging"
       "PYTHONPATH": "/opt/python/current/app/django-myapp:$PYTHONPATH"
     "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
       WSGIPath: myapp/wsgi.py
       NumProcesses: 3
       NumThreads: 20
     "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
       "/static/": "myapp/static/"
   ```
4. Commit to git and deploy with `eb deploy`.

P.S. to show the favicon from the static directory, I had to add its full path in the `base.html` template:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}site/img/favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just copy your own wsgi.conf (httpd conf) to parent directory and that way your file will be used instead of the default.

```
container_commands:
  03_wsgireplace:
    command: 'cp . ebextensions/wsgi.conf ../wsgi.conf'
```